# How to install 'Ckeditor' for 'Active Admin' with 'Rails 3.1'

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I looking for how to install Ckeditor for Active_Admin

I already installed Ckeditor and I have put this line in my 'initializers/active_admin.rb' file.

> # To load a javascript file:
>   config.register_javascript
>   'ckeditor/config.js'

And the line

> config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)

in my 'config/application.rb'

In the begining the 'config.js' file wasn't loaded because when I install Ckeditor gem it creates a folder named Ckeditor in public/javascripts but with rails 3.1, I had to move this folder into assets/javascripts...

That's what I've done.

Now the file "config.js' is loaded.

But now I don't know what I have to do next

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3.2

activeadmin-0.4.3

in 'initializers/active_admin.rb' file.

```
  config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' 
  config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/init.js'
```

in form

```
 = f.cktext_area :text
```

Answer (score 2):

If your're using the assets pipeline with external host server you have to hack a little bit.

Your `assets/javascripts/active_admin.js` should look like this:

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require_self
//= require ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require ckeditor/init

var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://assets.yourdomain.com/assets/ckeditor/';
```

Then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
```

to the start of your ckeditor.js file.

I believe you are having an issue with the new location of the files in rails 3.1. Make sure all your ckeditor files are located in the javascript/ckeditor folder (or modify the link accordingly).

See http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Specifying_the_Editor_Path

Answer (score 1):

You can also use in your forms

```
f.input :name, :as => :ckeditor
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [page](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/CKEditor-integration) in the oficial wiki for this task.